Strapi enum values change based some value
Is it possible in strapi to set different enums based some value?
I want to change my enums list based my exercise type, because I want to others who used admin panel for menage exercise data will able only chose existing enums based of exercise type.
I tried do it in my controller function but it don't updated my enum, so what else I can do?
exercise.data.attributes.exercise_type = ['Weightlifting', 'Bodyweight', 'Resistance'];


That is not going to work with enum, however it’s possible with JSON or customField
